# Codeigniter is not sending base_url in mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, sendmail

this is my first question, normally I found everything here, but this time I can't find anything anywhere.

I am building a project with codeigniter 2.2, that each time that a new user register a welcome mail is sent. The problem is that the mail is successfully sent but if in the message body the url of my website appears the email is not received, if there is another URL the email has no problem and it is received.

```
Example 1
Mail message: <h1><a href="'.site_url().'">Welcome</a></h1>
The print debugger: Your message has been successfully…
In the email: Nothing received…

Example 2
Mail message: <h1><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Welcome</a></h1>
The print debugger: Your message has been successfully…
In the email: Nothing received…

Example 3
Mail message: <h1><a href="http://www.google.com">Welcome</a></h1>
The print debugger: Your message has been successfully…
In the email: Mail received, welcome message with google URL
```

If I echo de site_url() on any view, it appears with no problem. The problem is only if I want to send it via codeigniter email, or write it and send it.

My server is Linux in godaddy. I am using sendmail with gmail's smtp, I've tried with another servers, host, user and pass, like yahoo, hotmail and another website and is the same result, the mail is only received when it has another URL, any URL except mine.

It that a bug? please help

Comment: Have you set mail type as HTML?

Comment: yes, as html, with newline \r\n and everything

Comment: Are you using any library to generate mail content?

Comment: I am using codeigniter's mail library

Comment: i've tried with phpmailer and nothing, a simple php form and nothing, i tried in a subdomain in another server, not go daddy, and it worked, i called go daddy and they say their servers are working fine, that is something in my code

Comment: No need to say but have you tried mail function itself? or checked in phpinfo whether mail function is disabled or not?

Comment: it is enabled, the mail is received only if in the body message is not written my hostname, if the url is any other them message receives with no problem, even go daddy's phone support laugh because they have no idea what could be doing this, i tried on another host company as a subdomain and everything works perfect, it is some go daddy configuration

Comment: Have you got something on this? I got same error @Jose Pablo Nava